# Using (multi lexeme) grails targets in gant scripts

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, gant

I have a gant script in my grails project.

I would like to do something just like this:

```
includeTargets << new File ( "${grailsHome}/scripts/War.groovy" )
war()
```

But for the deploy target in the script provided by the tomcat plugin.

Specifically, I would like to invoke this target:

```
grails prod tomcat deploy
```

how would that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I did not really understand your usecase. I assume you wanted to execute tomcat deploy from within your application's gant script. If so, here's the way to go:

```
includeTargets << new File ( "${grailsHome}/scripts/Init.groovy" )
includeTargets << new File("${pluginsHome}/tomcat-${grailsVersion}/scripts/Tomcat.groovy")

target(default: "convert csv files into properties files") {

     list() // should implicitly call "grails tomcat list"
}
```

~